# Drupal (6.19) cron exhausts memory when doing search indexing

Tags: php, drupal, memory-management

My Drupal 6.19 installation has been running about six months. Client has been activately using it publishing more content.

However, something has happened, because now cronjob does not finish.

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36230464 bytes) in /XXX/modules/search/search.module on line 444

As you see, I have 128M memory limit in PHP.ini and search.module is trying to allocate quite big amount, 36M. Because I cant come up with any reason why search.module would do that, I ask you guys if you have any hints how I could proceed further. Increasing memory limit is not possible as Drupal is in hosted environment.

I've limited indexing down to 10 nodes at time and changed shortest word length to 5 characters. I can't understand how indexing 10 nodes would anyhow consume all that memory.

How to debug? What to try? Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Memory consumption is based not only on the number of nodes you index but also on the modules you've got activated. If you have lots of active modules (or a few resource hungry modules like CCK/views), Drupal will gobble down a lot of RAM.

Comment: My bad folks. I didn't understand, that also comments are indexed. And other thing that i didn't notice was, that I had just a bit over 250 000 spam comments which took about 600M space from filesystem. One can ask: how you can miss that. Answer is: You shouldn't. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at line 444 in /XXX/modules/search/search.module, what's the code there?

I think we need to know more about the content of your site. How big is the site? How many nodes? How much text per node, approximately?

Check in your database, how much storage do your nodes use? What's the size of the entire database?

Do you have a module installed that allows you to search attached files and files on the file system (like http://drupal.org/project/search_files)?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you say the client has been publishing more content. We have no information about how much memory was previously being used by the cronjob. Most likely you were right under your memory limits until just recently, and now you have gone over. This kind of things happens all the time when people who don't know what they are doing put up websites.

How to proceed further? Bump up your memory allocation for the search module. I mean that seems a bit obvious. Are you worried that this won't scale? Well you don't really know for sure, because you haven't profiled the problem until now.

One thing to think about is that a search engine is a way of trading disk space for I/O when a search is run. Either you scan all of your documents (using I/O) for each search, or you look at the indexes (on disk) to get the information. So it is natural that a cron script to index your site would require a certain amount of memory (as a kind of temporary disk space) to get the job done.

Comment: All correct points -- put I don't see how any of them will help @Jasmo solve his problem.

Answer (score 0):

My first suspicion is that there's a big 'ol whopper of a node in the queue that's putting you over the limit. There are a few ways to test for this:

Check the `search_dataset` table in your database for the largest `sid` that corresponds to a node one your site. Then, look at the nodes with larger `nid`s than that. Is one of them abnormally large, or otherwise weird? Try editing it to have a blank body (be sure to keep the old revision) and see if that helps.

If not -- comment and we'll try something else.